A/B test question - How to test significance for metrics that are not the unit of randomization
We're runnning an AB test on an ecommerce website. The feature being launched is not for the "users" that come to buy products on the website but is rather for "suppliers" who add their products on the website.
More specifically, it's a feature that allows suppliers to create products using AI. (AI will pre-populate fields based on some text they provide.)
Now we want to test for two things:

Success metric: Do suppliers find the feature useful? (based on conversion of when they start creating a product -> completing the product addition flow and publishing it online successfully)
Guardrail Metric: We also want to test if the products they added have impact on user side metrics e.g CTR/CR on the products they added e.g "Product XYZ" created via AI should not negatively impact user performance in terms of CTR/CR etc.

Here's the variation split we went with:
A (not exposed to the AI product assistant)- 25%
B- 75% (since suppliers can still opt-out of creating their products via AI and we wanted to get a large enough supplier base using AI)
Here's the problem:

The randomisation is done on the supplier level and not on the product level which is out main success metric (the supplier can opt-in and use AI to create their product or not for each product addition)
The randomisation is also not done on the "user" level which is forms our guardrail metric
The distribution is highly skewed for guardrail metrics - Around 10% of the suppliers contribute to a 75% of user impressions/clicks/conversions
Some suppliers can create a whole bunch of products and not convert. This also skews data for the success metric

My questions:

I ran an AA test and saw that guardrail metrics were not flat even before the experiment. Larger groups (i.e B assigned 75%) would outperform A most of the time, and this would increase if a changed the split to e.g 90-10. Is it correct to assume this would be because of the skew and "better" suppliers likelier to be part of the bigger group?
My success metric is also on a product level and not a supplier level and wasnt stable before the experiment. I drew random samples 1000 times with 75-25 splits and saw that 50% of the time the metric was flat, 25% A performed better and 25% B performed better. Is this possibly because of how randomization is done on a supplier level and this does not translate well into product level because some suppliers can create a lot of products
What methods can I use to run my AB test given that the AA test reveals the setup is possinly not valid OR how do I still make reliable conclusions for my success and guardrail metrics when they are not the units of randomization?
I'm using a two proportion Z test to calculate significance. Given the 75-25 split is this still the right way to go?

If you made it to the bottom of this essay, thank you!! :)
